# How to replace certain tags in a page with nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace the double occurence of a certain with blanks but it is not working for me.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zq0p2fu9/4/

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var vRepText = "<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>";
  $("<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>").replaceWith("");
});
```

To put in simple term. I would like to remove all the `P` that are repetitive with just a space.

How can I achieve it.

Original:

```
<myText>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>First Text</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Second Text</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>Third Text</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</myText>
```

Final:

```
<myText>
    <p>First Text</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...</p>
    <p>Second Text</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...</p>
  <p>Third Text</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...</p>
</myText>
```

Comment: you need to add them to a parent element right? can you show a sample of the HTML?

Comment: Updated my question...

Comment: if I am understanding you correctly, you only want to remove `<p>nbsp;</p><p>nbsp;</p>` and not `<p>nbsp;</p>` if it is not consecutive, correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: I have added my answer - one line in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 2):

### Regex for Duplicate Empty Paragraphs

You can use regex to find repeating empty paragraphs and replace with a single empty paragraph.

https://jsfiddle.net/swr4b4yL/2/

```
$(function() {
    var bodyHtml = $("body").html();
  bodyHtml = bodyHtml.replace(/(<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\s*)+/g, "<p>&nbsp;</p>");
  $("body").html(bodyHtml);
});
```

### Select and Remove All Empty Paragraphs

You can loop through the paragraphs and remove where .html() equals the "`&nbsp;`"

https://jsfiddle.net/crf1b7qm/2/

```
$(function() {
    var paragraphs = $("p");
  for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++){
        var paragraph = paragraphs[i];
    if($(paragraph).html() == "&nbsp;"){
        $(paragraph).remove();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This works. However I want to remove only if it appears twice in a row, otherwise keep it as is as shown in my question.

Comment: hmmm, that is more complicated. I'm thinking you could get the body html as a string and do a regex replace, matching on `(<p>&nbsp;</p>\s*)+` and replacing with only a single instance

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$(function() { 
     var allParagraphs = $('p');

   // Check all tags <p></p>
   allParagraphs.each(function(){
     var currentElement = $(this);
     var nextElement =  currentElement.next('p');

     /* We check 3 condition:
     1. Content in current element is empty string
     2. Next element is <p></p>
     3. Content in next element is empty string
     */
     if( isEmptyString(currentElement.text()) &&
         nextElement.length &&
         isEmptyString(nextElement.text())
     ){
        /* 
        If all conditions is true we will remove current element because allParagraphs is live collection. And this approach can cover case when you will have serial of emtpy elements 
        */

        currentElement.remove();
     }
     });

     function isEmptyString(str){
          return $.trim(str) === '';
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Other solutions are removing all instances of `<p>&nbsp</p>` or leaving behind one `<p>&nbsp</p>` from a consecutive pair when you clearly want both consecutive elements removed.**

### Simple one line solution, vanilla JS

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(?:<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\s*){2,}/g, '');
```

RegEx Notes:

- `(?:<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\s*)` non-capture group for `<p>&nbsp<\/p>` with any amount of trailing spaces, tabs, newlines.
- `{2,}` must have at least two of the previous token to match.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yL2eH2/1)

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(?:<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\s*){2,}/g, '');
```

```html
<myText>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>First Text</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Second Text</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>Third Text</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...This is a random text we see...</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</myText>
```

To check, you can inspect in the console and see that all consecutive `<p>&nbsp;</p>`s have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you try to call to just simple html.
As far as I know it's not possible this way to do that.
You need to call to something like a HTML tagg, class, id.
Your JavaScript/JQuery code would look something like this:

```
$(".someClass").replaceWith("Some other text here.");
$("#someID").replaceWith("Some other text here.");
$("div").replaceWith("Some other text here."); // this one represents a html tag
```

I've forked your fiddle and gave you a fast/little exapmle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmvvavjn/2/

Comment: It is not doing anything, it is the same fiddle that I included? Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you. The only thing is, those `P` is auto generated and I can't put a class on it, unfortunately.

Comment: Let me think of a better solution then

Answer (score 0):

you can loop using jquery each :

```
$(function() {
  $("p").each(function(i){
    if ($("p")[i + 1] &&
        $("p")[i].innerHTML === '&nbsp;' &&
        $("p")[i + 1].innerHTML === '&nbsp;' )
       $("p")[i].replaceWith = '';
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zq0p2fu9/6/

Comment: I put that in my asp.net page and I am getting a syntax error in `=>`

Comment: @Si8 it's probably because arrow function isn't supported , you can fix that by using `function` instead; I also  changed `remove`  with `replaceWith` because remove effects the index/array position (in case you should loop backwards to fix that)